# Why are segwit transactions cheaper than legacy transactions?

Tags: transaction-fees, segregated-witness, output, address-format

What's the reason to make fees for segwit addresses lower, while keeping legacy addresses with higher fees? --
I'm interested in both, why segwit transactions are cheaper than legacy addresses, and why legacy addresses still exist when they are more expensive.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/52196/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/43596/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/84004/5406

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Why are segwit transactions cheaper?**

Segregated witness transactions are cheaper because they are *designed* to be.

In legacy transactions, every byte has the same "cost"; they all count equally towards the 1000000 byte block limit. Segwit transactions on the contrary keep certain data (signatures etc) in a separate "witness" section, and that witness section is discounted: every witness byte only counts as 0.25 byte towards the block limit. Fees are determined by the market and not a system rule, but the fact that segwit transactions have some of their content discounted results in the market pricing them less.

There is a reason why this discount is justified: in legacy transactions, creating a transaction output is significantly cheaper than spending one. This encourages unspendable dust: outputs that were created at a time when fees were low may become uneconomical to spend (= cost more to spend than they're worth) when fees are high. This is a burden on the entire ecosystem, as full nodes (for now, at least) need to maintain fast access to the set of all unspent outputs.

**Why are legacy transactions still in use?**

Compatibility. There is little more to say about it: they're still permitted because it would be impossible to get a change that broke people's existing software without an extremely good reason. And people still use them, because they haven't upgraded their infrastructure to use segwit transactions - the engineering costs to perform this upgrade may be (rightfully or not) considered higher than what would be gained by upgrading.

Comment: Nit: The blocksize limit is dead, long live the blockweight limit.

Comment: @Murch Yes, though I wanted to avoid going into those details. Describing the witness as being discounted 0.25 towards the 1000000 limit is equivalent to the actual specification, I think?

Comment: So why is the witness section discounted? Is it somehow cheaper to store and transfer?

Comment: It is cheaper because the rules say it is. The justification for that rule is that indeed, they don't burden the network as much: outputs add to the UTXOs set, but inputs remove from it. Only inputs have a witness section, so a transaction with more inputs (i.e. one that will be discounted a lot) is less of a burden on the network.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be incentive for the use of a more efficient type of transaction which has lower concern to network scalability.