# Effect of the witness data discount on the UTXO set

Tags: segregated-witness, utxo-set, statistics

Part of the rationale to apply the witness data discount was to incentivize transactions to spend more inputs and promote a smaller UTXO set. Are there any data on the success of this pursuit?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43596/why-is-the-witness-data-fee-discounted-by-a-factor-of-four/

Answer (score 3):

> **[...] incentivize transactions to spend more inputs [...]. Are there any data on the success of this pursuit?**

[image: inputs/tx and segwit tx]

I guess this is data, but you'll have to draw your own conclusions.